# Day by day weekly report in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one table named as Order.I want my output as shown below.Please if possible give me sql query.Stored Procedure receive two dates parameter and for every week it show report like this.i-e if i pass first parameter  10/02/2014 and second 16/02/2014 and similar if dates varies then for every week it should produce like this.Thanks

```
Day         Date          Sales
Monday      10/02/2014    100
Tuesday     11/02/2014    120
Wednesday   12/02/2014    140
Thursday    13/02/2014    160
Friday      14/02/2014    180
Saturday    15/02/2014    10
Sunday      16/02/2014    78
```

Comment: I'm not sure i understood he question. But if you want to count the amount of sales per day, you just need to grop by date and count (select count(sales) from table group by date [will not work, it's just to clarify what i mean])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know every date is going to have at least one entry something along the lines of the following will work:

```
SELECT 
    Day = DATEPART(DAYOFWEEK,dateColumnName)
    , Date = dateColumnName
    , Sales = COUNT(*)
FROM
    salesTable
GROUP BY 
    dateColumnName
```

If it is possible that there are dates with zero sales then you should consider a temporary table or adding a dates table to your database and joining with this.

**Edit:**

```
SELECT 
    Day = DATENAME(DW,dateColumnName) -- Wrong function previously used this will get the name
    , Date = CONVERT(VARCHAR, dateColumnName,103) -- this returns in format dd/mm/yyyy other codes are available
    , Sales = COUNT(*)
FROM
    salesTable
GROUP BY 
    DATENAME(DW,dateColumnName)
    ,CONVERT(VARCHAR, dateColumnName,103)
```

Other codes are nicely described in [this article](http://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-format-datetime-date-in-sql-server-2005/).

Adding the following code to a stored procedure with the required parameters (I've called them `startDate` and `endDate`) means you could call this each week by executing the stored procedure providing the parameters. ([Here's some Microsoft documentation on how procedures are used](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174792%28v=sql.80%29.aspx))

```
CREATE PROC procedureName (
   @startDate DATETIME
   ,@endDate DATETIME
) AS 
SELECT 
    Day = DATENAME(DW,dateColumnName) -- Wrong function previously used this will get the name
    , Date = CONVERT(VARCHAR, dateColumnName,103) -- this returns in format dd/mm/yyyy other codes are available
    , Sales = COUNT(*)
FROM
    salesTable
WHERE
    dateColumnName BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
GROUP BY 
    DATENAME(DW,dateColumnName)
    ,CONVERT(VARCHAR, dateColumnName,103)
```

There are potential disadvantages of having 2 parameters as you could actually show more than 1 week. You could create it with a single parameter and use the `DATEADD` function to add or remove 7 days to determine the start/end date from the single date provided.

Comment: What if `dateColumnName` is of type `DATETIME`

Comment: I've updated the query, corrected the use of `DATEPART` to `DATENAME` and updated the `Date` column to be converted to a `VARCHAR`. The original code does assume `DATE` column rather than `DATETIME`, but the second converts to a string and groups accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for reply .But please tell me.I want to pass two parameters of datatype date.And between these dates i want my every week record should like this as show in question

Comment: I wasn't intending on writing all the code for you and hoped that you would be able to create a stored procedure yourself but have added the relevant code.

Comment: you are amazing.I got what i want...:)

Comment: I want little modification that i want the sum of Sales Column of full week.Can you help me.Please

Comment: Look into Sql Aggregate functions, you'll be interested in `SUM` for totaling sales, this probably will need doing with a `UNION`, you won't need to define the `GROUP BY` for that. I'm sure there are plenty of articles on here regarding aggregates and weekly totals.